# String > 0 in GTM. How?

Tags: javascript, types, google-tag-manager

Have a very simple example in Google Tag Manager with data types. I have 2 variables `'- 5'` and `'6'`

[image: 2 variables]

`5 + 6 string = 56`, right!

But when I return a Boolean value with the condition string 56 > 0 number, how does it write true?

[image: 56 string > 0 number how?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A numeric string will usually get [coerced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) to a Number for mathematical operations and comparisons, but there are exceptions to this like the `+` operation. See @Eike's example:

> the "+" sign is an exception in that it does not trigger an implicit type conversion when one of the operands is a string. Other mathematical operators do implicit type conversion. So `"5" + "6"` is `"56"`, but `"56" > 0` is converted into `56 > 0`, which evaluates to `true`.

```js
console.log("5" * "6"); // coerce
console.log("5" < "6"); // coerce
console.log("5" + "6"); // no coercion
```

Comment: OPs question is why does `console.log("56.4" + "56.3");` output `56.456.3` which is correct :/ but *56 is > 0*, why does it write true

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, the "+" sign is an exception in that it does not trigger an implicit type conversion when one of the operands is a string. Other mathematical operators do implicit type conversion. So (string) 5 plus (string) 5 is (string) 56, but (string) 56 > 0 is converted into (int) 56 > 0, which is true.